# fatal: reference is not a tree: develop

Tags: git, gitlab

We are on GitLab 6.2.1-0 & Git 1.8.3
I was trying to accept the merge request from develop branch to prod branch, and GitLab UI won't let you accept the merge request. Clicking on "Accept Merge request" doesn't do anything. Digging deeply, its happening only for a single project, which started to show up "fatal: reference is not a tree:" errors in host.log

It was working up until we did a recent reboot of the GitLab server

```
February 16, 2016 10:29 -> ERROR -> Command failed --git-dir=/opt/gitlab-6.2.1-0/apps/gitlab/gitlab-satellites/projectname/.git checkout develop    
fatal: reference is not a tree: develop
February 16, 2016 10:29 -> ERROR -> Command failed --git-dir=/opt/gitlab-6.2.1-0/apps/gitlab/gitlab-satellites/projectname/.git push origin prod
error: src refspec prod does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to '/opt/gitlab-6.2.1-0/apps/gitlab/repositories/projectname.git'
```

Navigating to the git project directory, shows it is currently on _parkingbranch, wherein all other projects would show develop branch

```
cd /opt/gitlab-6.2.1-0/apps/gitlab/gitlab-satellites/projectname
git status
# On branch __parking_branch
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

I tried switching the branch to develop, but didnt help.

```
git checkout develop
fatal: reference is not a tree: develop
```

This is happening on the actual git server itself and not on my local machine.
Any pointers highly appreciated.

Comment: According to that log, there is no branch called `develop` in that repository.

Comment: Strange, is it possible to recover?

Comment: If you try to push the `develop` branch from a computer that still has it, what happens? `git push origin develop`

Comment: I am able to push it locally and the new changes I made are reflected globally. However, gitlab git-host.log throws up errors still..

Comment: git fsck shows 2 hashes that has dangling commits dangling commit 8736d022deb8d8eb46b4a3045482900230957dcf
dangling commit c479e849714ee8adca7b78d9cbadbcc281aad8e2

Comment: With little more insight, I am guessing it appears only the gitlab satellites directory which is probably a staging area for handling the merge requests looks somehow corrupted, not the real git repo itself. Thats the reason local push or pull works ok. I need to look into how to recreate the gitlab satellites

Comment: I deleted and recreated the problematic satellite directory by running below command. However, the merge request doesn't work and noticed git status still shows __parking_branch on the satellites directory. Strange, there is no proper documentation on how the gitlab satellites work. I am stuck..

    bundle exec /opt/gitlab-6.2.1-0/apps/gitlab/htdocs/bin/rake gitlab:satellites:create RAILS_ENV=production

Answer (score 1):

The answer is late, but I had a similar problem. I was trying to make a pull in a old branch, but the same messsage was being displayed, so I created a local temp branch, and did a hard reset with the branch in origin. Then I renamed the temp branch to have the name it had in origin.

In resume, these were the steps:

1. Create a local branch

   git checkout -b temp
2. Do a hard reset with the desired branch

   git reset --hard origin/branch-name
3. Rename the temp branch

   git branch -m branch-name

Answer (score 0):

Using Xcode Version 14.3 beta 2 (14E5207e) resetting packages caches fixed this problem for me.

I suspect that the problem was caused from trying to use Xcode released and beta versions on the same project without correctly clearing then project manually.